# How do I create a fixed-length, mutable array of Python objects in Cython?

Tags: python, arrays, cython, trie, python-c-extension

I need to have an array of python objects to be used in creating a trie datastructure.  I need a structure that will be fixed-length like a tuple and mutable like a list.  I don't want to use a list because I want to be able to ensure that the list is *exactly* the right size (if it starts allocating extra elements, the memory overhead could add up very quickly as the trie grows larger).  Is there a way to do this?  I tried creating an array of objects:

```
cdef class TrieNode:
    cdef object members[32]
```

...but that gave an error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef class TrieNode:
    cdef object members[32]
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/jason/src/pysistence/source/pysistence/trie.pyx:2:23: Array element cannot be a Python object
```

What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about the *best* solution, but here's *a* solution:

```
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject, Py_XINCREF, Py_XDECREF

DEF SIZE = 32

cdef class TrieNode:
    cdef PyObject *members[SIZE]

    def __cinit__(self):
        cdef object temp_object
        for i in range(SIZE):
            temp_object = int(i)
            # increment its refcount so it's not gc'd.
            # We hold a reference to the object and are responsible for
            # decref-ing it in __dealloc__.
            Py_XINCREF(<PyObject*>temp_object)
            self.members[i] = <PyObject*>temp_object

    def __init__(self):
        # just to show that it works...
        for i in range(SIZE):
            print <object>self.members[i]

    def __dealloc__(self):
        # make sure we decref the members elements.
        for i in range(SIZE):
            Py_XDECREF(self.members[i])
            self.members[i] = NULL
```

A Cython `object` is an automatically refcounted `PyObject *`.  You can always roll your own arrays of `PyObject *`'s as long as you take responsibility for refcounting the little buggers.  This can be a major headache for non-trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need few fixed sizes of such a structure, I'd look at making classes with uniformly named `__slots__`, including one `size` slot to store the size. You'll need to declare a separate class for each size (number of slots). Define a `cdecl` function to access slots by index. Access performance will probably be not as great as with plain address arithmetics of a C array, but you'll be sure that there's only so many slots and none more.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
class TrieNode():
   def __init__(self, length = 32):
      self.members = list()
      self.length = length
      for i in range(length):
         self.members.append(None)

   def set(self, idx, item):
      if idx < self.length and idx >= 0:
         self.members[idx] = item
      else:
         print "ERROR: Specified index out of range."
         # Alternately, you could raise an IndexError.

   def unset(self, idx):
      if idx < self.length and idx >= 0:
         self.members[idx] = None
      else:
         raise IndexError("Specified index out of range (0..%d)." % self.length)
```

Comment: My preference is `assert 0 <= idx < self.length, "index out of range"` Much smaller than the whole `if`-`else` construct.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't even in the right ballpark of what I'm looking for.  Two things:  1)  I was looking for a way to do this in cython to create a C extension. 2)  I don't have any way to force the list to take up exactly 32 elements.  It has a `len` of 32, but usually more space is allocated to make appending easier.