# If I have a list of words, how can I check if string does not contain any of the words in the list, and efficiently?

Tags: python, search, loops, filter, stop-words

As title says, I have a list of words, Like `stopWords = ["the", "and", "with", etc...]` and I'm receiving text like "Kill the fox and dog". I want the output like "Kill fox dog" very efficiently and fast. How can I do this (I know I can iterate using a for loop, but thats not very efficient)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most imporant improvement is to **make stopWords a `set`**. This means the lookups will be very fast

```
stopWords = set(["the", "and", "with", etc...])
" ".join(word for word in msg.split() if word not in stopWords)
```

If you just want to know if any of the stopWords are in the text

```
if any(word in stopWords for word in msg.split()):
    ...
```

Comment: Is it more efficient than making a regex?

Comment: @mlt, possibly not. The work so differently to this that it's hard to guess. You should write an answer using a regexp

Answer (score 3):

With Python the fastest operation will be making "stopwords" a set instead of a list and checking directly for membership with "x in stopwords".  This structure is designed to be fast for this sort of operation.

[See the set documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Answer (score 1):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
stopWords = ["the", "and", "with"]
msg = "kill the fox and the dog"

' '.join([w for w in msg.split() if w not in stopWords])
```

gives:

```
'kill fox dog'
```

Comment: `w not in stopWords` will get slower as stopWords gets longer since it has to iterate through the list to check each one. This is why making stopWords a set is important

Comment: @gnibbler Ok, so noted, thanks. Always happy to learn something new (I don't use sets nearly often enough)

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your original list of words in a dictionary.
2. Iterate through the characters in the given string, using space as a delimiter for a word. Look up each word in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Have your stopWords in a `set()` (as others have suggested), accumulate your other words into a working set then simply take the set difference using `working = working - stopWords` ... to have a working set with all of the stopWords filtered out of it.  Or just to check of the existence of such words use a conditional. For example:

```
#!python
stopWords = set('the a an and'.split())
working   = set('this is a test of the one working set dude'.split())
if working == working - stopWords:
    print "The working set contains no stop words"
else:
    print "Actually, it does"
```

There are actually more efficient data structures, such as a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) which could be used for large, relatively dense, set of stop words.  You can find trie modules for Python, though I didn't see any written as binary (C) extensions and I wonder where the cross-over point would be between a trie implemented in pure Python vs. use of Python's `set()` support.  (Might also be a good case for [Cython](http://www.cython.org/), though).

In fact I see that someone has tackled that question separately here [SO: How do I create a fixed length mutable array of python objects in cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834036/how-do-i-create-a-fixed-length-mutable-array-of-python-objects-in-cython).

Ultimately, of course, you should create the simple set-based version, test and profile it, then, if necessary, try trie and Cython-trie variants as possible improvements.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can assemble your list in a regex and replace stop words along with surrounding spaces by a single space.

```
import re
stopWords = ["the", "and", "with"]
input = "Kill the fox and dog"
pattern = "\\s{:s}\\s".format("\\s|\\s".join(stopWords))
print(pattern)
print(re.sub(pattern, " ", input))
```

will output

```
\sthe\s|\sand\s|\swith\s
Kill fox dog
```

Comment: You should `re.escape` the `stopWords` in case they inadvertently contain any regex special chars